# Java object mapper deserializer set value for a field based on a value from another field

Tags: java, jackson

I have a class that maps a JSON object to a POJO. One of the fields in the POJO is an enum and that enum has a value with an annotation `@JsonEnumDefaultValue`

This means that if the JSON file contains a value that isn't part of the enum it sets the field to a default value.

I want to add a new field in the POJO called `originalValue`. Over here I want to set the actual value present in the file. The input file cannot be modified.
I assume I'll need to write a custom deserializer for the enum field, but I'm not able to figure out how to set the value in the original class instance.

Enum:

```
public enum Status {
   Success,
   Failure,
   @JsonEnumDefaultValue
   Unknown
}
```

Pojo:

```
public class Report {
   Status status;
   String inputStatus; //Set this field to actual value passed.
}
```

File input:

```
{
   "status": "garbage"
}
```

Expected Pojo:

```
{
   "status": "Unknown",
   "inputStatus": "garbage"
}
```

Comment: Providing a getter `getStatus()` with a corresponding implementation should do the trick. Alternatively, we can provide a setter for `inputStatus`, which also sets `status`.

Comment: @Turing85 How would getStatus work? Because getStatus is providing the enum value. If we have a setter for inputStatus, will Jackson use that? I'll need to tell Jackson to get original value of the status field

Comment: Still didn't follow. If I do something like setStatus(final Status status), it has already deserialized to the enum and lost the original value.

Comment: Sorry, I read it the wrong way around. We can instruct jackson to use a constructor for deserialization (see [`@JsonCreator` (`fasterxml.github.io`)](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) and [this article at `baeldung.com`](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#bd-1-jsoncreator)). The construcot should then have only a single `String`-argument, annotated with `@JsonProperty("status")`. Within the constructor, we can do the necessary logic and value assignment.

Comment: I see. I also have other fields in Report class that are non null. Is there a way for me to extend the deserializer and say, when you encounter the field status, set the originalStatus field before you do your thing of converting to an enum

Comment: I do not completely follow. There is also the way to make fields private, use the default constructor and setters. the setter for `inputStatus` would then be annotated with `@JsonProperty("status")` and se tthe `status` enum field as well (based on the value of the parameter passed along). The filed `status` should then be annotated with `@JsonIgnore`. Do you have a reproducer, e.g. a git repository?

Comment: [Her is a `github.com` repository](https://github.com/turing85/jackson-deserialization) showing the setter approach.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following solution:

```
public class MyMappingTest {

    public enum Status {
        Success,
        Failure,
        Unknown;

        public static Status valueOfElseNull(String s) {
            for (Status value : values()) {
                if (value.name().equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                    return value;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class Report {
        Status status;
        String inputStatus; 

        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.inputStatus = status;
            this.status = Optional.ofNullable(Status.valueOfElseNull(status)).orElse(Status.Unknown);
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testMapping() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Report report = objectMapper.readValue("""
          {
            "status": "garbage"
          }
          """, Report.class);

        Assertions.assertThat(report.inputStatus).isEqualTo("garbage");
        Assertions.assertThat(report.status).isEqualTo(Status.Unknown);
    }
}
```

The thing is that Jackson uses setters to construct a POJO from JSON. So I can create a setter (optionally annotate it with `@JsonSetter` to hint the Jackson about the field I want the value for in this setter, but here it is not necessary since the name of the field is deductible from setter method) that just accepts `String`, and then do whatever I want. So I think a custom deserializer could be a bit of a heavy weapon here, there is an easier path.

Answer (score 0):

We have the challenge that the actual json has a field `"status"`, which we want to map to two target-fields in our object: one field `String statusText`, which holds the raw input and one field `Status status`, which represents the Enum-equivalent of the `statusText`.

First, I suggest introducing static helper methods to the `enum Status` in order to get an `Enum`-value based on a `String`-representation. This may look something like this:

```
public enum Status {
  // @formatter:off
  SUCCESS,
  FAILURE,
  @JsonEnumDefaultValue
  UNKNOWN;
  // @formatter:on

  public static Optional<Status> getByName(String name) {
    return Arrays.stream(Status.values())
        .filter(
            status -> status.name().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).equals(name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)))
        .findFirst();
  }

  public static Status getByNameOrDefault(String name, Status status) {
    return getByName(name).orElse(status);
  }
}
```

(I took the liberty and wrote the `Enum` values in upper case)

With these in hand, I see two general options:

- We can provide a custom setter for the field `inputStatus` in class `Report` that receives the `String`-value of the json field `"status"` and do the necessary logic there, or
- We can provide a constructor that receives the `String`-value of the json field `"status"` and do the necessary logic there.

---

### Setter-based approach

The approach would look like this:

```
@Getter
public class Report {
  private Status status;
  private String inputStatus;

  @JsonProperty("status")
  public void setInputStatus(String inputStatus) {
    this.inputStatus = inputStatus;
    this.setStatus(Status.getByNameOrDefault(inputStatus, Status.UNKNOWN));
  }

  @JsonIgnore
  private void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
  }
}
```

We see that we do the mapping in `setInputStatus(...)`. Important here is the `@JsonProperty("status")` annotation. Since the setter-name and the actual property name in the json diverge, we have to align them through this annotation.

---

### Constructor-based approach

This implementation would look like this:

```
@Getter
public class Report {
  private final Status status;
  private final String inputStatus;

  @JsonCreator
  public Report(@JsonProperty("status") String inputStatus) {
    this.inputStatus = inputStatus;
    this.status = Status.getByNameOrDefault(inputStatus, Status.UNKNOWN);
  }
}
```

Her, we are doing basically the same as in the setter-based approach, but we use the constructor instead. Notice, however, that we can make the fields of `Report` final, thus creating an immutable object. If the json had more properties, the constructor would need more arguments - one per json property.

---

### Testing the implementation

We can use the same test(s) for both implementations:

```
class ReportTest {
  private static final String JSON_TEMPLATE = """
      {
        "status": "%s"
      }""";

  @ParameterizedTest
  @EnumSource(Status.class)
  void deserializeStatusWithKnownStatus(Status status) throws JsonProcessingException {
    // given
    final String expectedInputStatus = status.name().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
    final String json = JSON_TEMPLATE.formatted(expectedInputStatus);
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // when
    final Report report = mapper.readValue(json, Report.class);

    // then
    Truth.assertThat(report.getStatus()).isSameInstanceAs(status);
    Truth.assertThat(report.getInputStatus()).isEqualTo(expectedInputStatus);
  }

  @Test
  void deserializeStatusWithUnknownStatus() throws JsonProcessingException {
    // given
    final String expectedInputStatus = "foobar";
    final String json = JSON_TEMPLATE.formatted(expectedInputStatus);
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // when
    final Report report = mapper.readValue(json, Report.class);

    // then
    Truth.assertThat(report.getStatus()).isSameInstanceAs(Status.UNKNOWN);
    Truth.assertThat(report.getInputStatus()).isEqualTo(expectedInputStatus);
  }
}
```

---

### Sample code

The full code for both approaches ins available on github:

- [here (`github.com`)](https://github.com/turing85/jackson-deserialization) for the setter-based approach, and
- [here (`github.com`)](https://github.com/turing85/jackson-deserialization/tree/with-ctor) for the constructor-based approach.

The project is maven-based. To build and run the tests, we can run `mvn clean package`.